# JQuery - Direct child of direct child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can anyone help me. I have a table containing a nested table in one of the cells. I want to append "hello world!" to the first cell in each row of the outer table (so in the below html I want to append to cells 1a and 2a only). I tried the following:

```
$("div > table > tr > td:first-child").append(' Hello World!');
```

on the below html:

```
<div class="divClass">

    <table class="tableClass" border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>1a</td>
            <td>1b</td>
          </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>2a</td>
            <td>2b
              <table border="1px"><tr><td>nested table cell</td></tr></table>

            </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</div>​
```

but it doesn't work. ( - http://jsfiddle.net/NickyW/x3bqf/ )

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("div > table > tbody > tr > td:first-child").append(' Hello World!');
```

You need to just use `tbody` because it added to table by browser. This is more reliable.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x3bqf/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple all you need to do is add tbody, there is no need to reference the div and please use the class reference.

```
    $(function () {

        $(".tableClass > tbody > tr > td:first-child").append(' Hello World!');

    });
```

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/x3bqf/6/)

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean with append? you want to set the value of the cell to Hello world?

Then you should try it with $(..).html(' Hello World');

If yuo want to append it to the 1a for examle:

Try it with $(..).html($(..).html()+" Hello World");

Comment: Use jQuery `append()` to append instead of concatonating several `html()` calls, that is what it is intended for.